# Cannot GET error with node back end

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am coding the backend of my server I don't know why my code is giving me an error. This is my code below.

```
//@routes Get api/profiles/handle/:handle
//@desc Get frofile by handle
//@access public

router.get('/handle/:handle', (req, res) => {
  const error = { };
  Profile.findOne({handle : req.param.handle})
  .populate('user', ['name', 'avatar'])
  .then(profile => {
    if(!profile){
      errors.noprofile= "There is no profile for this user";
      res.status(404).json(errors)
    }

    res.json(profile);
  })
  .catch(err => res.status(404).json(err))
});
```

This is the url I GET using postman.

http://localhost:5000/api/profiles/handle/sambulo

I GET THE ERROR below I don't know whats wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>Cannot GET /api/profiles/handle/sambulo</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try using full route `api/profiles/handle/:handle` instead of `/handle/:handle`

Answer (score 0):

You have the error in the routing.

Try this code:

```
router.get('/api/profiles/handle/:handle', (req, res) => {
    // Your code here
}
```